# Short science fiction story in which cyborgs are treated equally as humans

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, robots, cyborg, society

Last year I read a science fiction story online, but I forgot the name of the story.

Roughly, the story goes like this:

> Imagine, in a futuristic society, where the cyborgs were treated equally as humans. They get elected in politics, they become teachers, players, actors...everything a human could've become.
>
> - They're smart, their processor helps them to become smarter than humans!
> - They've developed human consciousness, they can love, hate etc.

The rules are new; people don't ask them anymore if they are cyborgs, and the law prohibits them from doing so! So you never know the person whom you met, is a cyborg or not. They get married, have children, they have every potential to call them human.

But, imagine, you're from the era where people were skeptical about this whole new cyborg thing and one day, a guy met a girl.

The guy eventually fell for the girl, and started to love her. One fine evening, while taking with her, he realized that what if she maybe a cyborg. The guy asks the girl if she's a cyborg, and the girl says something in reply (but I forgot the exact reply).

**EDIT :**

> I forgot to mention earlier, there was an video in YouTube telling the story like an audiobook format. And, you can guess already, now I can't find that YouTube video too.

Comment: Do the cyborgs have biological components, or are they robots in a human form?

Comment: "Cyb-Org" = cybernetic organism.  If they're fully synthetic they aren't cyborgs, they're robots or possibly (if they look human) androids/gynoids.

Comment: @ZeissIkon It's a mistake that's made often enough to be worth asking about.

Comment: It sounds like one of those totally dire cyborg romance books that my sister constantly reads

Answer (score 3):

I wonder if you're thinking of "Are You Real" which was published at DailyScienceFiction.com in July of last year.  https://dailysciencefiction.com/science-fiction/robots-and-computers/ian-e-gonzales/are-you-real

**The rules are new; people don't ask them anymore if they are cyborgs, and the law prohibits them from doing so! So you never know the person whom you met, is a cyborg or not. They get married, have children, they have every potential to call them human.**

> Not since the government declared, in a controversial case that went
> all the way to the Supreme Court, that humanoid androids were
> officially people, granted all the rights and responsibilities that
> went with the appellation. Now they were surrounded by laws and the
> cushion of political correctness, the center of fierce debate. As for
> what the androids thought about it, no one had actually asked them.

**One fine evening, while taking with her, he realized that what if she maybe a cyborg. The guy asks the girl if she's a cyborg, and the girl says something in reply (but I forgot the exact reply).**

> "I'll answer you the same way I answer everyone else," she said.
> Reaching out, she cupped his chin and raised his head until he was
> staring into her eyes again. "If the ability to feel what others feel
> is the only thing that separates humans from androids, tell me... are
> you real?"

Comment: The storyline is exactly the same, but the story I am looking for was in a bit tough English language and it was bit dry in nature. More of all, there was an video in YouTube telling the story like an audiobook format. And, you can guess already, I can't find that YouTube video too. @Andrew

Comment: Thanks for coming back with this response.  Maybe add the info about YouTube to the original question.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I added the  info about YouTube to the original question. @Andrew